# Non numeric value always occurs

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to translate this Javascript code into PHP, but when I do, it gives me a message for a non-numeric value.

Every time I var dump `count($fin)`, it gives me a different index compared to the `console.log` in JavaScript.

Code in JavaScript:

```js
var countAndSay = function(n) {
    var str = '1';
    for (var i=1; i < n; i++) {     
        var strArray = str.split('');
        str ='';
        var count = 1;
        // Loop through current nth level line
        for (var j=0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
            // Next digit is different
            if (strArray[j] !== strArray[j+1]) {
                // Go to next non-matching digit
                str += count + strArray[j];
                count = 1;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
};
console.log(countAndSay(45));
```

And here is my code in PHP :

```php
function countAndSay($n) { 
    $str = "1";  
    for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) { 
        $fin = str_split($str);
        $str = "";
        $len = count($fin); 
        $cnt = 1;
        for ($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++) { 
            if ($fin[$j] !== $fin[$j +1]) { //error for non numeric value
                $str += $cnt + $fin[$j]; 
                $cnt = 1; 
            } else {
                $cnt++; 
            }
        }
    }
    return $str; 
}
echo countAndSay(9);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript the `+` operator is also a string concatenation operator, while in PHP `+` is always the arithmetic addition. For concatenation in PHP you should use the `.` operator.

Secondly, in JavaScript you can use an out of range index in an array (which gives you a value of `undefined`), while in PHP it will produce an exception. This happens in your code when `$j+1` is equal to `$len`, so you should add a condition to deal with that case.

Here is the part you need to correct:

```php
            // protect against out of range index:
            if ($j+1 >= $len or $fin[$j] !== $fin[$j +1])
            { 
                // Use string concatenation operator
                $str .= $cnt . $fin[$j]; 
                $cnt = 1; 
            }
```